# Open "emacs -nw" and running a command from bash

Tags: terminal-emacs, command-line-arguments

I would like to know if it is possible, with a single command from bash, to open a file with `emacs -nw`and execute a command in the same time, for example `goto-line 20`.

Comment: Related/Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18033190/1219634

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Generic solution

Here's a generic solution to eval some elisp expression after launching emacs

```
emacs --eval="SEXP"
```

For your example, that will be

```
emacs -nw --eval="(goto-line 20)" FILE
```

*Also check out  the `--load` option from the below referenced link if you want to load an elisp file instead of writing elisp at command line.*

#### Solution specific for opening emacs at a particular position

From the command line, if you want to open a specific FILE and position the cursor at a specific LINE and COL, you would do

```
emacs +LINE:COL FILE
```

Of course, as you want to jump to a specific line number in terminal mode, you can do

```
emacs -nw +LINE FILE
```

#### Reference

- [Emacs Manual - Command line Action Args](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Action-Arguments.html#Action-Arguments)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I need to run also different commands such as elisp script. Is there a general way to to this?

Comment: Updated my answer with the generic solution as well

Comment: The command with `goto-line` is not working for me (the file is opened with the cursor at the beginning of the file). Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The answer to this question seems to be this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18033190/start-emacs-from-shell-with-predefined-lisp-code

Comment: Was the fix changing the order of `--eval` and `FILE`? I am not next to a computer currently. You can correct this solution, or I will when I get next to a computer.

Comment: It's `emacs -nw +LINE FILE` actually

Comment: @artemave Thanks. I have fixed the order of "+LINE" and "FILE".